# installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS on ASUS UX303LN

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

i'm trying to install ubuntu on my laptop asus UX303LN in dual boot mode, but i got some problem.

my configuration :
GPU : GT840m, Hd 4400
CPU : i5 - 4210u
HDD : 500GB
SecureBoot : Disabled
CSM : enabled

ISO : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with rufus (MBR mode, USb boot).

Result :
get a black screen when i try to install ubuntu or trying to test ubuntu without instal.

if i switch using the key

> CTRL + ALT + F1

i got two error :

> unknown maxwell chipset.
>
> unknown chipset.

ive tried with the "nomodeset" command, but i still have the black screen.

Any ideas to resolve the problem ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why "Disabled CSM : enabled"?

Comment: Hello, should i disable it ?

Comment: Try it. There is no need to disable secure boot or UEFI mode. And this laptop should work well with Ubuntu. And read the linked answer.

Comment: ive already changed the CSM to disabled, but it seems the error, are still the same, black screen when i try to boot ubuntu with the USB.

Comment: Is it 14.04 or 14.04.2?

Comment: it's 14.04.2 of ubuntu

Comment: Try 15.04. It may be that 3.16 kernel does not support the video chip at all.

Comment: hello, after trying to install ubuntu 15.04, instead of black screen i get a little error "the system is running in low graphic mode".

Comment: That's better. You can use `nomodeset` to continue and after the system is installed try proprietary drivers. There must be a new video adapter in this hardware revision.

Comment: hum, the problem is, with nomodeset, i still get the error.

Comment: But can you install?

Comment: hello, no i can't, still get the error, with or without the `nomodeset` option.

Comment: There is no simple solution, I am afraid. Open source drivers may not support it at all, or you need a newer kernel. The easiest option is to try unstable 15.10. Or manually install a custom kernel, then everything else. But I can't give you a smiple guide for that.